# Except ValueErrors

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, exception, try-catch

I'm a beginner at programming with python and confused on how exceptions work. I'm creating a menu list and dictionary for a restaurant and for the cost of item if user types in invalid number or a string I need it to except the value Error and ask the user again but still getting a value error code

```
while True:
    try:
        itemCost = float(raw_input("Please enter the cost of this item (ex: 22.45): "))
        if itemCost < 0: print "Invalid Number, please try again"
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid Number, please try again"
    except NameError:
        print "Invalid Number, please try again"
    except SyntaxError:
        print "Invalid Number, please try again"
```

---

**Update:**

This is what im entering but still getting a Value Error code because i used a string instead of a float but want it to give the user a error message.

```
Please enter the menu item name (quit to exit): Chicken

Please enter the cost of this item (ex: 22.45): rrr

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Stan/Documents/Intro to Programming/Program Project #2.py", line 14, in <module>
    itemCost = float(raw_input("Please enter the cost of this item (ex: 22.45): "))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: rrr

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What are you entering?

Comment: Works fine for me.  If it doesn't work for you, show your exact input and the complete output..

Comment: The code shows the `itemCost = float(...` statement inside a `try` statement.  The sample output in the update shows the output one would get if it was _not_ in a `try` statement.